# Пожалуйста помогите не могу понять

Tags: kotlin, for

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var y = 20
    for(outer in 1..3) {
        for (inner in 4 downTo 2) {
            y = 7

            y= y +1
        }
       
           y = y-2
    }
    
       println("$y")
}
```

Не могу понять почему данный код выдает  y = 6

Comment: А сколько должен выдавать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во внутреннем цикле происходит приравнивание Y семи и прибавление единицы, и сколько это не повторяй, на выходе внутреннего цикла всегда будет 8. А во внешнем цикле от Y отнимается два. Получается три раза повторяется Y = 8; Y - 2;